# Why does JPA "order by ascending" returns upper case entries first?

Tags: java, jpa, sql-order-by

I have a criteria query with the following code:

```
CriteriaQuery<MyClass> criteria = cb.createQuery(MyClass.class);
Root<MyClass> root = criteria.from(MyClass.class);
criteria = criteria
        .where(cb.like(root.get(MyClass_.name), name + "%"))
        .orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(MyClass_.name)))
        .select(root);
```

Why is my example result ordered this way:

```
abcdE
abcde
```

and not like this:

```
abcde
abcdE
```

and how can I fix that?

I would expect the result that's completely lower case to be returned first, but that's not the case.

Comment: I think you will accept the behaviour and won't look for solutions, given the implementation costs of a possible solution.

Comment: @AndreiI there's no problem sorting the data on Java rather than retrieving it sorted from database. This is done in most applications and there's no problem with this approach, and it's not implementation costly.

Comment: I have a different opinion: try to paginate and sort some 100.000 records in memory, having some tens of users using your app simultaneously.

Comment: @AndreiI that's not a problem in these days. Seems like you're still living in the past, when you only had 32 MBs of RAM for your server and more synchronization problems.

Comment: Ok, lets do the Math: fetching 100.000 records (entities with their relationships) means 100.000 instances *  100 bytes/instance = 10^7 bytes = 9Mb (per user). If you multiply by the number of concurrent users (suppose 100 users) add also footprint of the entire framework + JVM then I think you could get some problems. Of course I ignored the time needed to load the data from HDD and sort the data.

Comment: @AndreiI if I have to fetch 100'000 records I would seriously ask: why? what's the task to be done? Me as an end user will seriously review 100'000 elements in a view, can I seriously check **all of them**? No? Then why not to use pagination instead and show the relevant items, let's say, in blocks of 50 elements rather than 100'000? Also, to check 100'000 elements I would prefer to get a report and don't work with that data directly from my app, and I will group the data rather than working directly with it.

Comment: @AndreiI in case you need these elements for some specific work like batch processing, I will retrieve them only once, and there is no need of N users, only a single client that retrieves the data and keep it in memory until it's processed. If it's data that should be checked from time to time, I would think on caching it and synchronizing it with the proper data source in case it's modified. But then, we're going to other problems and possible solutions that doesn't apply for OP's problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The usual task to be done is: sort the list (according to the criteria the OP need) and display pages of them to the user. I am not sure how to take all those data from DB and sort in memory, as you proposed, so that only page `k` is correctly displayed .

Comment: @AndreiI you could create a field on the fly for the SELECT where you provide a calculated value from a column you want/need to sort but it's not that easy to compare, then sort by this field. I don't know if you can do that with JPA (and one reason I dislike it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode character points for A-Z are from 65 to 90, while for a-z are from 97 to 122. So, the ordering is right from the database.

To *solve* this (because this is not an issue but a different requirement you have to fulfill) simply don't sort the data using JPA but manually by using `Collections#sort` and provide a custom `Comparator<MyClass>`.

Comment: Sorting in Java is not an option in my case but the first part answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Because in char code for uppercase letter are before lower case letter.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think it really depends on the DB and collation... And besides, no one said anything about ASCII. Also, the codes in ASCII or Unicode are the same for those letters.

Comment: @AndreiI Jens edited the post to remove the wording about ASCII. And it doesn't depend on DB collation, once the data gets to Java all the characters are in the charset used by the JVM (implementation dependent).

Comment: No sorting is done in Java (in no JPA implementation) and that is alone the task of the DB.

Comment: @AndreiI you're wrong. If you have a `List<SomeClass>` then you can apply `Collections#sort(List<SomeClass>, Comparator<SomeClass>)` despite how you got the data for the `List`: database, external service, reading directly from socket, etc.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I thought the OP was looking for a solution in JPA (as the title says), and not to for the clear solution of sorting the data in memory. But may be you right: the OP did not see that solution. PS: of course all these comments are not meant to offend ANYONE.

Comment: I am mainly looking for a solution in JPA, because I can't know in advance how many results the query would return and will most likely have to paginate it. So sorting it in Java is not desirable.

Comment: @MatthiasSchippling then you can do nothing to solve this. Sorry.